# How to get new access token with Google Identity Services after login

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, google-account, google-identity

I'm currently using `google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient` and then `tokenClient.requestAccessToken()` to prompt the user to select an account. Then, I'm using the access_token from the `TokenResponse` of https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/reference/js-reference#TokenResponse and sending that param to my server to login.
The issue I have is for `google.accounts.oauth2.revoke()`, since that now requires a valid access token as a parameter.
However, since the access token expires after an hour, is there any way to get a new access token without making the user go through the UX flow again with `requestAccessToken()`?

```
    _googleClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
      client_id: _clientid,
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
      callback: function (tokenResponse) {
        _accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token; additionalOptions);
      },
      error_callback: function (err) {
        console.log('err:', err)
      }
    });
    _googleClient.requestAccessToken();
```

Comment: You're wanting to revoke an *expired* access token?  Wouldn't that, for all intents and purposes, **already** be considered "revoked" (in a manner of speaking)?    Maybe some clarity on your full intent would help us out...

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: @FrankAlvaro Sorry, I meant I want to accomplish something like [GoogleUser.disconnect()](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleuserdisconnect). This is deprecated now, and I thought that the equivalent of that in the new library is `google.accounts.oauth2.revoke()`, is it not? The google reference says it is: https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#library_quick_reference

Comment: I think you may want to be looking at implementing [refresh tokens](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/token-types#refresh), and managing them.

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios here.

Either you are happy with the 1-hour expiration, and don't have the security/user need to revoke the token before this. In which case, you just wait until it expires.

Or you want a long-lived token, and the ability to revoke it later on. In this case, you need to use the GIS Code flow (see [this doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-code-model)) or a Server side implementation (see [these pages of Google's doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow)).

This Code flow is a bit more complicated (not a lot) and gives you an Authentication code which you can exchange for an Access + Refresh token. With the Refresh token, you will be able to refresh the Access token without having to prompt the user for consent again. You will also be able to revoke these code at any time.